# In R using source(external function) to count odd numbers in rows of a data frame

Tags: r

```
odds_evens <- function(df){
odds <- 0
for ( n in df){
    if(n%%2==1){
        odds<-odds+1
    }
}
odds
```

}
I want to use this function in another function and on a different data set: naively I supposed that I would include source("reference to the file") and then use lapply(data, odds_evens) to count the number of odd numbers in every row of a data set. 
I get both after the console runs source(filename) and when the function called within my second function:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (X[[1]])
```

Could someone kindly explain what is going on. Still new at this!

Comment: This is *not* how things done in R. `%%` is vectorized, thus no need in a `for` loop. Also, One does *not* grow objects within loop. All you need to do is `odds_evens <- function(n) sum(n%%2)`. Then you can test it, for example `n <- sample(15) ; odds_evens(n)`

Comment: Thank you for this. And to use odds_evens in another function? How do I go about that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Have you tried using it? Did yo get any error?

Comment: The error I mentioned above. I have changed odds_evens in the way that you suggested which of course worked perfectly( thank you for that). I tried apply(my_data, 1, odds_evens) which caused the error{Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (X[[1]])}

Comment: I noticed that I left out odds_evens(n). Inserting that gave the correct result. Thank you very much

Comment: `apply(my_data, 1, odds_evens)` should have worked. You could provide and example data and the code you've tried